# Laravel 5 Property [userType] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel-5

I keep getting property [userType] does not exist error when Im trying to make log in condition
here is my Controller code below. I also tried to make Auth controller but I just keep getting the same error from this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use App\User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function redirectTo()
{
    $user = User:all();
    if($user->userType == 'admin')
    {
        return 'dashboard';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'verify first';
    }
}
}
```

and here is my model code

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *  protected $table = 'users';
    *public $primaryKey ='id';
     * @var array
     */
  
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','userType',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

   
}
```

anyway on how can I fix this? Please show me the correct way to create a redirect in login because I just want to create a login with admin, user, and guest mode.

Comment: `User:all();` gets all of the users into a collection. It is not a single user. Maybe you're thinking of `Auth::user()`, which gets the logged in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very clear erorr

```
 protected function redirectTo()
{
    $user = User:all();
    if($user->userType == 'admin')
    {
        return 'dashboard';
    }
    else
    {
      
        return 'verify first';
    }
}
```

in `redirectTo` method you are accessing `$user = User:all();` instead one record .It may be `Auth::user()`  or `User::find($id)`

```
$user = User:all();
```

all return multiple records so you cant access userType directly

Instead of using `redirectTo` to you can use `authenticated method`

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
   if($user->userType == 'admin')
        {
             return redirect()->route("dashboard");
        }
        else
        {
           auth()->logout();
            
        }
}
```

Comment: how can I access userType directly? If use User::find($id); I keep getting Undefined variable If I use this

Comment: Instead of using redirectTo() to you can use authenticated() method

Comment: @Kaye.any issues then let me knw

Comment: use Illuminate\Http\Request;  import this

Comment: have you imported use Illuminate\Http\Request; this  ?

Comment: by the way I have error on other role it says Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth' not found

Comment: in which php file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233177/discussion-between-kaye-and-john-lobo).